# factory restore Acer D255

Tags: windows-7, acer-aspire

My uncle installed Windows XP on my Acer D255 but I would like to use Windows 7.

I want to use factory restore but <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> does not work for me and I do not have a restore CD.

How can I access the recovery partition or check to see if it exists?

Comment: Use disk management to mark the recovery partition as "active", then restart the PC, hopefully it will boot into the recovery partition and load recovery.

Comment: This forum thread says that you can download a W7 ISO and then use the key on the sticker that cam with your PC: http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1856339